# Built-in webcam not working

Tags: lenovo-laptop, webcam

I have a Lenovo G550 (model 20023) laptop with a built in webcam running on Windows 7. The camera recently just stopped working and it isn't shown under imaging devices. I've uninstalled and reinstalled, updated drivers, tried everything. How can I know if its broken or not? Keep in mind I got this laptop from 2010.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it's not detecting as an anything at all is pretty telling, especially in an 8-year-old laptop.  If you were to disassemble it, chances are the only thing connecting that laptop to its camera is a thin wire that is soldered on one end to the motherboard, or a ribbon cable that is usually not insulated.  In both cases, solder can crack and ribbons can degrade.

The best thing you can do is boot it with a Linux CD and have Linux drivers on hand to load for your camera.   If the camera still isn't detected, you know it's done for.  If it is, something may be preventing it from being loaded in Windows, which is a security concern.   Chances are, it's just dead.